# Error MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []:

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm getting the error First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []:. Goal is to find existing User History record & create a new one if a User record is updated and matches the criteria. When I checked the debug log, I do see the query finding the existing User History record Id so I'm unsure why it not able to see the User History Id.

```
public class UserHistory_CreateUpdateFromUser  {

public static void findUser(List<User> newUsers, Map<Id,User> oldUsers, Boolean isInsert){

    List<User> newUserList = new List<User>(); 
    List<User> lOBChannelList = new List<User>();
    List<User> isActiveList = new List<User>(); 
    List<User> uManagerLOBChannelList = new List<User>();
    List<User> uManagerList = new List<User>(); 
    Map<Id,List<User>> reasonForUpdatingUser = new Map<Id,List<User>>(); 

    for(User u : newUsers){
        //New user && Channel != Non Sales  
        if(u.Channel__c != 'Non Sales'){
            if(isInsert){ 
                newUserList.add(u); 
                System.debug('newUserList: '+ newUserList); 
            }
            //Existing user && Channel || LOB is changed 
            else if(!isInsert && (u.Channel__c != oldUsers.get(u.Id).Channel__c || u.LOB_Focus__c != oldUsers.get(u.Id).LOB_Focus__c)) {
                lOBChannelList.add(u); 
                System.debug('lOBChannelList: '+ lOBChannelList); 
            }
            //Existing user && deactived 
            else if(!isInsert && u.IsActive != oldUsers.get(u.Id).IsActive){
                isActiveList.add(u); 
                System.debug('isActiveList: '+ isActiveList);
            }
            //Existing user && Manager is changed && Channel || LOB is changed 
            else if(!isInsert && u.ManagerId != oldUsers.get(u.Id).ManagerId &&
                    (u.Channel__c != oldUsers.get(u.Id).Channel__c || u.LOB_Focus__c != oldUsers.get(u.Id).LOB_Focus__c)){
                uManagerLOBChannelList.add(u); 
                System.debug('uManagerLOBChannelList: '+ uManagerLOBChannelList);
            }
            //Existing user && Manager is changed 
            else if(!isInsert && u.ManagerId != oldUsers.get(u.Id).ManagerId){
                uManagerList.add(u); 
                System.debug('uManagerList: '+ uManagerList);
            }
        }     
    }

    if(newUserList.size()>0){
        newUser(newUserList);
    }   

    if(lOBChannelList.size()>0){
        lOBChannelUpdate(lOBChannelList); 
    }

    if(isActiveList.size()>0){
        userisActiveUpdate(isActiveList); 
    }

    if(uManagerList.size()>0){
        managerUpdateOnly(uManagerList); 
    }

    if(uManagerLOBChannelList.size()>0){
        managerLOBChannelUpdate(uManagerLOBChannelList); 
    }

}

public static void lOBChannelUpdate(List<User> lOBChannelList){
    //Find existing User History record and update end date fields 
    //Create new user history record and update fields based on user changes 

    List<Id> userIds = new List<Id>(); 
    List<User_History__c> existingUHtoUpdate = new List<User_History__c>(); 
    List<User_History__c> newUHtoInsert = new List<User_History__c>(); 

    for(User u : lOBChannelList){
        userIds.add(u.Id); 
    }
    System.debug('userIds: '+ userIds);
    System.debug('lOBChannelList: '+ lOBChannelList);

    if(userIds.size()>0){
        List<User_History__c> eUH = [SELECT Id, User__C, Role_End_Date__c, Manager_End_Date__c FROM User_History__c
                                        WHERE User__c =:userIds]; 
        System.debug('eUH' + eUH); 

        for(User_History__c uH : eUH){

            //if(eUH.size()>0){
                User_History__c existingUH = new User_History__c(); 

                if(uH.Role_End_Date__c == NULL){
                    existingUH.Role_End_Date__c = Date.today(); 
                    //existingUH.Id = uH.Id;
                }
                else if(uH.Manager_End_Date__c == NULL){
                    existingUH.Manager_End_Date__c = Date.today(); 
                    //existingUH.Id = uH.Id;
                }
                else if(uH.Role_End_Date__c == NULL && uH.Manager_End_Date__c == NULL){
                    existingUH.Role_End_Date__c = Date.today(); 
                    existingUH.Manager_End_Date__c = Date.today(); 
                    //existingUH.Id = uH.Id;
                }
                existingUHtoUpdate.add(existingUH); 
            }
        //}

    }
        System.debug('existingUHtoUpdate: '+ existingUHtoUpdate);

        for(User u1 : lOBChannelList){

            User_History__c newUH = new User_History__c(
            User__c = u1.Id, 
            Channel__c = u1.Channel__c,  
            LOB_Focus__c = u1.LOB_Focus__c,  
            Role_Start_Date__c = Date.today(), 
            Manager_Start_Date__c = Date.today()
        ); 
            newUHtoInsert.add(newUH); 

        }   
        System.debug('newUHtoInsert: '+ newUHtoInsert);
    }

    if(!existingUHtoUpdate.isempty()){
        Database.update(existingUHtoUpdate); 
    }
    System.debug('Databaseupdate existingUHtoUpdate: ' + existingUHtoUpdate); 

    if(!newUHtoInsert.isempty()){
        Database.insert(newUHtoInsert);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You retrieved the record Ids but you didn't assign them to the `existingUH` object.  Changing to this line should fix it:

```
User_History__c existingUH = new User_History__c(Id = uH.Id);
```